# Call AngularJS 1.5 component's method from the controller?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have component plugged into my main page like this

```
<rs-dropdown></rs-dropdown>
```

The component is defined as RsDropdownComponent class with a reference to RsDropdownController, the usual stuff...

The component has $onInit() event handler that calls some datastore to populate the component with some data, this event is fired once the component is initialized.

The problem is that I dont want the component to start loading data onInit() event.

I want to be able to call the component's method from my controller when I want to.

Basically I need somehow to access the instance of the Component from my controller and call it's load function.

Is it possible?

Comment: You could rewrite the component to expose a function that can be called instead of using `$onInit()` but the whole idea of not allowing a component to initialize itself is against the principles regarding the design of components.  Basically, this is a sign of poor design of either your component or your app if the component can't operate independently of the state of the parent app.

Comment: I aggree that doing so is a bad practice. It can be achieved though. You can simply add your init function as a property to an unidirectional binding and call it from the outside (i do not recommend this). A different approach would be to add an $onChanges listener and set a binding from outside when you want the component to really initialize. Still bad, but it feels a little less bad.

Comment: Claies, I understand, you rush to judge the design which you have not even seen, lol. Besides the component id built by someone else, not me. The component needs to load itself (dropdown options) based on a data that is loaded into a controller via a promise, meaning with a delay, when this happens is technically unknown, but the component will already be initialized. How do you handle that?

Comment: "Call the method from my controller when I want to." When is that? Manual action? Event? It looks like you should have the parent component hold the data and make it available to the child (when you want) through attributes. (thus it looks like you just need a directive. A component helps structuring your page.

Comment: The data in parent controller is received AFTER the component is initialized. Component need that data as a parameter to load itself with dropdown options.

Answer (score 2):

Someone already mentioned using ng-if, that or making your child component more lenient to asynchronous inputs is always a better approach if possible, but there's many things you can do.

1 - You can always use eventing, create a simple event service with signatures like:

```
service.registerEventHandler(id, function)
service.unregisterEventHandler(id, function)
service.sendEvent(id)
```

Register a handler in the child, and fire the event from parent when ready

2 - dark magic using 2-way bindings.
In child component specify

```
bindings: {
  darkMagic: '='
},
controller: function() {
  this.$onInit = function() {
    darkMagic = function() { 
          // data ready
    };
    ...
```

Then from parent template `<child data-dark-magic="$ctrl.placeholder">....`
Then in parent controller, after compile, after postlink after digest cycle... you can call `this.placeholder();` to execute the function defined in the child.

3 - you can use one-way binding with onChanges to toggle state

```
  controller: function() { 
    this.ready = false; // should use onInit but saving lines
    this.$onchanges = function(changesObj) {
        if (changesObj.isReadyProperty) {
            this.ready = changesObj.isReadyProperty.currentValue;
        }
    }
  },
  bindings: {
    isReadyProperty: '<',
  }
```

Then from parent you have `<child is-ready-property="$ctrl.imready">...`
And just toggle imready to true in controller when data is loaded.

There is also the case when the child is ALWAYS under the parent, good example of this is a tabset component and tab components. In this case the child (tab) component can require the tabset controller, and use the API defined there.

Or you could even use a service for communication, inject the service into both components, and maintain state that way. Keep in mind with this solutions though to use factory patterns and not maintain state in angular recipes.

I'm sure there's even many more ways, but it really depends on your use-case.

I still prefer to just make your component more lenient to handle the no data case gracefully until it receives something.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1.First of all you can always use ng-if, usually this is done when you use some vendor's component:

```
<rs-dropdown ng-if="loadDropdown"></rs-dropdown>
<div> smth? here or mb another component </div>
```

2.In current project we do this using triggers:

```
<rs-dropdown load-data="loadDataTrigger"></rs-dropdown>
```

3.Of course you can add angular event for this. Not that flexible thow.

Comment: something like that, but what is "load-data"? how is load-data triggered? lets say I have a controller as vm, and vm.data is data that is loaded into the controller async, via a promise. The component by that time is already created, initialized and destroyed. How would you tell the component to load something when vm.data is loaded?

Comment: I believe he is talking about the "dark magic" that I mentioned in my longer reply below. Here is a plunkr example of it in action: https://plnkr.co/edit/nySL4OoMpJPkGXX8j78U?p=preview
Basicaly the parent passes a reference to trigger that is nothing, but due to the way 2-way binding works, once the child defines it in $onInit, the same function is updated in the parent as well, and can then be used by the parent (like the button ng-click)