# How can angularjs component detect that data is loaded in parent controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I have a **MainController** aliased **vm**, that has a property **vm.data** that is loaded from some **DataService**.

The View of the Controller has a custom component **rs-dropdown**, that is supposed to load dropdown values once the vm.data is loaded. vm.data is a property of Main Controller.

Is there any way how the **component itself** can watch for changes in parent MainController and, once the data is loaded, perform its load action?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** Thanks Clavies, adding ng-if="condition" to the component actually makes this component to be created and initialized once the condition is true. Looks like angular constantly monitors ng-if and turns the component ON when the condition is met.

Here I added `ng-if="vm.woReAssign"` attribute to my component, and now the component with be initialized and created only when this condition is true.

```
<rs-dropdown ng-if="vm.woReAssign"
                rs-server-controller="WorkOrder"
                rs-server-action="GetServiceProviderDropDownList"
                rs-filter="{woNum:'{{vm.woReAssign.WorkOrderNumber}}'}"
                rs-class="form-control">
</rs-dropdown>
```

P.S. Even though the condition becomes true via async calls with possible delay, it seems that Angular checks this condition all the time, and then revives the component.

Comment: how is this any different from the question you asked [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661644/call-angularjs-1-5-components-method-from-the-controller)?  other than the fact that you are providing less information here than on the previous question, when multiple comments suggested that we would like to see *more* information (and code) to understand what it is you are really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: as I tried to explain on the question yesterday, if the behavior of the element is tied to the behavior of the parent, then it's not a good candidate for being a component, and probably should be a directive instead.

Comment: What could be any simpler than that? 
Can component monitor if some controller's property has changed, why do you want to see code?

Comment: I am not sure how it can be explained any other way.  Components are **standalone**.  They are **isolated**.  They are not designed to interact with other elements on the page, except when data is **explicitly** passed in to them.  As for seeing code, that's a standard for questions here;  Seeing the code you have written both gives us the ability to see your approach to the problem instead of making guesses, and gives some reference for testing and troubleshooting.

Comment: so I guess, if you are suggesting your question is simple and you want a simple answer, it would be "they can't", at least not the way you are hoping.  If you are willing to provide some [mcve] of the problem, then we can work out a way to get your desired behavior.

Comment: as an example, if your component accepts the data the controller is fetching as a parameter, then you could use `ng-if` to not render the component until the data is ready to be passed to it.  There are other techniques that could be employed as well, but the responsibility is probably on the parent element, not the child component.

Comment: Perfect !! Mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the scenario you mentioned. You can listen the controller update via lifecycle  [lifecycle hook](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html) $onchange in component desing.

See the [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5pB7WgxnEmObhNzQGGXd?p=preview) where dropdown component gets filled when data is populated into parent controller on button click.Hope this helps!

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("mainController", function(bookService, $scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.showDropdown = false;
  vm.loadBooks = function() {
    bookService.getAllBooks().then(function(books) {
      vm.books = books;
      vm.showDropdown = true;
    }, function(err) {
      vm.showDropdown = false;
      //error
    });
  }
});

function dropdownControllerFn(bookService) {
  var model = this;
  model.$onInit = function() {
    //do intialization
  }

  model.$onChanges = function(changes) {
    model.books = changes;
  };
}

app.component("rsDropdown", {
  templateUrl: 'dropdownComponent.html',
  bindings: {
    books: '<'
  },
  controllerAs: 'model',
  controller: dropdownControllerFn
});

app.factory('bookService', ['$http', '$timeout', '$q', function($http, $timeout, $q) {
  var urlBase = 'favouriteBooks.json';
  var service = {};
  service.getAllBooks = function() {
    return $http.get(urlBase).then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  };
  return service;
}]);;
}]);
```

dropdownComponent.html

```
<div>
   <select ng-options="s.bookName for s in model.books" ng-model="selitem">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="mainController as vm">
  <rs-dropdown books=vm.books ng-if="vm.showDropdown"></rs-dropdown>
  <button ng-click="vm.loadBooks()">Get Books</button>
</body>
```